# Mounting IMU on Raspberry Pi

Tags: sensor

I want to order an IMU like this : https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/real-time-orientation-display-with-the-minimu-9-v2/, and mount it on the mainboard so that fits mecahnically and is stable. I found a way using AdaFruit GPS ( https://www.adafruit.com/product/2324 ) and sticking the IMU inside the holes and connecting them to the various pins ( Vdd, SDA , SCL etc. ) 
However I do not want any GPS.

Is there any other solution? What is HAT by the way in Adafruit?

EDIT, after some downvotes ( misunderstanding maybe ) for my answer: 
Is there any solution, wherein there is any alternative to Pololu and which fits mechanically on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a Pi specific question.  You want to know how to mechanically mount one object to another object which is a fairly generic question.  I suspect that any answer given will be dismissed as not quite perfect for your situation.  Does the Pi have a mounting hole?  Does the IMU have a mounting hole?  Why not use them?

Comment: @joan : i have written in my question the specific objects. I dont know how did you come to a conclusion that I want to fit any object to any object !? I have already found the answer .. See my answer below .

Comment: @joan I think the Pi's mechanical properties should probably be given equivalent weight to its electrical properties - mounting hole arrangements can be significant for some applications (although you can velcro your way out of just about anything).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

An alternative to Pololu is Sense-HAT

Luckily Sense-HAT has all the sensors that the Pololu-IMU has and also mechanically fits perfectly on the controller.

Hence, the Sense-HAT could be a good replacement to the IMU Sensors from Polulu MinIMU-9 v3.

[image]

Comment: While I'm pleased that you found an alternative approach to your issue, this is very much not the answer to the question 'How do I attach a Pololu MinIMU-9 v2 to a Raspberry Pi?'. If you plan on answering your own question there has to be some amount of logical consistency between Q & A. We do not play ['What's in my pocket?'](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Riddles_in_the_Dark) here.

Comment: @goobering : huh.. i wrote the question because i didnt know about this board at all. As I wrote in my answer, that its an alternative and alternatives are also answers ! Atleast I am sure, the answer would benefit one or the another someday.. So kindly stop accusing with "Whats in my pocket" and avoid the unnecessary pain of downvotes..

Comment: @infoclogged: It still doesn't answer the question you proposed, at all.

Comment: @Jacobm001 : I have asked for alternative solutions.. Just not for mechanically mounting, but also for if there is any alternative solution to achieve my goal - and the goal was to get IMU data from raspberry. Read the question properly dude, that I wanted a HAT which does not have a GPS..So, avoid the pain of downvoting unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

My initial guess would be to duct tape it to the back. I can't find any imu hats.

And a HAT is something you can put on your pi, so it stays like this.[image: this]