# Pi 3 B+, 7" official touch screen and a Sense Hat query

Tags: pi-3b+

New here, but wanted to ask about the above.
My Pi 3 B+ is connected to an official &" Touchscreen display, which uses a double adaptor to provide power to the Pi and scren. This work fine.

However, if I connect a Sense Hat to the Pi, the Pi doesn't boot fully. The Sense Hat does light up though, showing a rainbow of colours.
I am presuming this is a power issue.
Do I need to supply power to both the Pi and the screen separately?

I am asking before trying simply because it would mean a bit of a fiddle to provide power to both, although I could do it. I just don't want to break anything.

Any thoughts?

Regards  Phil C

Comment: OK, it looks like it IS a power issue. It works when I use separate supplies for the monitor and Pi, but I am still seeing the lightning flash when I run a script on the SenseHat.

Comment: Usually the yellow lightning only shows for short wile during boot, if you power supply is a little bit below.  But the lighting should disappear afterwards, NOT every time you run a script.  I suspect your power supply for the Rpi is a little below spec.

Comment: Many thanks, Yes, the power supply is not good enough, so I ordered a genuine Raspberry Pi unit, and that has cured my problem

Comment: you are welcome and how nice to hear that you solved your problem.  My Sense Hat is directly plugged into Rpi's 40 pin GPIO socket, so I once thought about messing around the connector pins to separately connect Sense Hat to another power supply.  Now you have convinced me that that this might not be necessary. Cheers.

Comment: There are advantages to separating the Sense Hat with a ribbon cable, especially if you plan to monitor the temperature. This is because the Pi gives off quite a bit of heat, so I purchased a 40 way cable to remove this issue.

Comment: Yes, your recommendation of using a ribbon cable to move the sense hat away is a good idea.  plugging the hat on top of the Rpi makes the GPIO pins not accessible. So I am using both a break out board and also a ribbon cable.  Now I can easily expand my GPIO wiring.  I am showing my config in the coming answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> Still seeing the lightning flash when running script on the SenseHat,
>   ...

***Answer***

> Me too.  The yellow lightning comes and goes.  My power supply is not
>   that good.  I am thinking of using separate power supplies, one for
>   Rpi, another for SenseHat.

*Using breakout board and ribbon cable*

Now I am using both breakout board and ribbon.  This way I can access the GPIO pins easily.  I am thinking of not connecting all GPIO pins the the Sense Hat.  I am going to use separate power supply for it.

[image: sense hat ribbon cable]

***Sense Hat Rewiring Notes***

Now I am rewiring the Sense Hat for separate power supplies.

[image: sense hat rewiring]

***References***

[1. Mounting Rpi Sense Hat and Polulu/AdaFruit IMU on Rpi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66585/mounting-imu-on-raspberry-pi)