# is there a way to minimise the effect of the Pi on the Sense HAT's temperature sensor?

Tags: python, temperature, sense-hat

Is there a way to minimise the effect of the Pi on the Sense HAT's temperature sensor?
I cannot seem to reduce it from mid to high 30s deg. C.
Or do I really need a sensor that is external to the computer?

Comment: Yes, Rpi3B+ is very hot, and Rpi4V even so. 
 One way is move the "HAT" from the Rpi board, using a ribbon cable, or connecting wires.  (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99339/pi-3-b-7-official-touch-screen-and-a-sense-hat-query )

Comment: Great suggestion.  Thanks, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Hi tlfong01, this worked well and reports very accurate number now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi user10570551, How nice to hear the good news.  Have a nice day.